# PostegreSQL Associatve Array Problem

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am running across this problem in PostgreSQL that I can't quite seem to figure out why it's happening. In PHP I have

```
$query="SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID=1";

$result=pg_query($query);
$row=pg_fetch_array($result);

print_r($row);
```

I notice the fields are missing that should be in the return value. But if I run that same query directly on the database (phpgadmin) it works fine. This problem has recently started. Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are there any errors raised when you connect to Postgres?  Are you connecting user the same user / password as `phpgadmin`?  Please post back the results of your `print_r`.

Comment: Could it be permission-related? Or that an uncommitted transaction altered the table?

Comment: Can you post a self-contained example?  I.e. create table, insert etc to create a test dataset then the code that fails against it?

Comment: Does PHP show any error message? Have you checked if the conection to Postgres have been done using pg_connect() or pg_pconnect()?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to use `pg_fetch_assoc` instead?

Comment: pg_fetch_assoc will the rows associated by name. pg_fetch_array does both name and number but I tried both and both have the same result.